# Bootstrap navbar not rendering fine

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very simple navbar code. But on putting this

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

this is being rendered in the next row of the nav-bar instead of the same row on the right hand side. Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Image attached.[image]

Below is my code.

```
![<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>APP_NAME</title>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
</nav> 


</body>
</html>][2]
```

Comment: Please give url of your site OR make Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you meant something like my example above then just remove the navbar-right.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
```